# Polymer paper-dialog with paper-input floatingLabel animation

Tags: polymer, material-design

I started today with Polymer, and I'm very excited with what I'm archieving with it! But i stumbled with a problem i don't know how to solve, if you add a `<paper-input floatingLabel>` inside an `<paper-dialog>`, the paper dialog loses the cool animation. There is any know workaround to get the animation, or it is a known issue when a animated component is inside another animated component?

As I received a vote down, i decided to provide code to help you people help me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- 1. Load platform.js for polyfill support. -->
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Use an HTML Import to bring in the element. -->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-overlay/core-overlay.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-transition/core-transition.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog-transition.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>

    <style shim-shadowdom>
        /* Coloquei Junto com os inputs */
        body {
            font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 24px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">

<core-toolbar style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
    <span flex>
        <img src="images/logo_Positivo.png"/>
    </span>
    <paper-button label="Login" class="colored" onclick="toggleDialog('paper-dialog-transition')"></paper-button>
</core-toolbar>

<paper-dialog heading="Login" transition="paper-dialog-transition" style="background-color: #efefef">
    <div>
        <img src="/images/academia.png" class="gym_logo"/>
        <img src="/images/default_user.png" class="usr_logo"/>
    </div>
    <!--<paper-input floatingLabel label="Chave"></paper-input><br/>-->
    <paper-input floatingLabel label="Usuário"></paper-input><br/>
    <paper-input floatingLabel label="Senha"></paper-input><br/>

    <paper-button label="Entrar" class="colored" affirmative default onclick="document.querySelector('#toast3').show();disparaLogado();"></paper-button>

</paper-dialog>

<paper-dialog heading="Login" transition="paper-dialog-transition" id="logado">

    Logado!!!

</paper-dialog>

<paper-toast id="toast3" class="capsule" text="Acessando o sistema e validando dados..." style="padding-right: 60px;" duration="5000"></paper-toast>
<script>
    function toggleDialog(transition) {
        var dialog = document.querySelector('paper-dialog[transition=' + transition + ']');
        dialog.toggle();
    }
    function disparaLogado() {
        selecionarModulos = window.setTimeout(function () {
            var logado = document.querySelector('paper-dialog#logado');
            logado.toggle();
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the following line at the end of the paper-dialog-transition.html:

```
<paper-dialog-transition id="paper-dialog-transition" transitionType="fade"></paper-dialog-transition>
```

Thanks for any help or comment!

Answer (score 0):

From your code I'm not sure whether you've tried this or not, but it did help me:

`<paper-dialog transition="core-transition-bottom">`

Now I have the animation back. The possible values to the `transition` attribute can be found in the [core-transition demo page](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-transition/demo.html).

Hopefully it helped

Comment: I will try it later, if it works, i check your answer... Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score -1):

I have been having problems with animations and all of them were solved by fixing absolute positions to the elements as the transitions need them.